# what is the posterior in the case of regression

Tags: regression, terminology, posterior

I am having trouble "mapping" the variables in the Bayes equation onto the case of regression.  As notation, say
$$ 
  P(\theta|D) = \frac{P(D|\theta) P(\theta)}{ P(D) }
$$
I have come to think of $\theta$ as parameters of a compact model.

Notation for regression:
$$
    y = f(x,\theta)
$$
or 
$$
    y = f_{\theta}(x)
$$

In regression we want to estimate both $y$ (after training) and $\theta$ (during training/fitting).
Is the posterior one of these:

- $p(\theta|y,x)$
- $p(y|\theta,x)$
- $p(y,\theta | x)$
- $p(\theta|x)$

Or perhaps the idea of posterior does not apply in typical regression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posterior will be $p(\theta|y,x)$, the posterior over the weights. The reason for this is you're not estimating $y$, you're estimating $\theta$. You can then use the posterior over the weights to ${predict}$ a new $y$ given a new $x$, using the posterior predictive distribution $$p(y_{new}|y_{previous},x_{previous},x_{new})=\int p(y_{new}|x_{new},\theta)p(\theta|y_{previous},x_{previous})d\theta.$$

It helps to write out explicitly what your likelihood and priors are. If you're placing a prior on a parameter then you're going to have a posterior over that parameter. You wouldn't place a prior on $y$, so why would you have a posterior over $y$? Try looking at the wikipedia page for bayesian linear regression (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_linear_regression) or one of the previously asked questions on this website ([Bayes regression: how is it done in comparison to standard regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/252577/bayes-regression-how-is-it-done-in-comparison-to-standard-regression)).